# livequery keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, livequery, execcommand

(Im using the `before()` function from jquery to append a new `<p>` element to a div layer.

```
$('#AddParagraphButton').click(function() {
    $('#TheLayer').before('<p contentEditable='true'>Some text...</p>');    
});
```

here I have set `keypress` function to insert `<br>` tag.

```
$('p').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
       e.preventDefault();  
       document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br/>');
    }
});
```

this works fine(br tag inserts) until the append function is called and a new `<p>` is added. How do I get livequery to unbind the *keypress* event and bind again?

**EDIT:** the `<p>` tags have the *contentEditable* property. Im doing this because the `<br>` tags are wrapped in divs and I only want `<br>` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the built in [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) functionality?..

> **Description:** Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

```
$('p').live("keypress", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      if(e.which == 13){
         document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br/>');
    }
});
```

Comment: I forgot to add that Im using contentEditable. this function now disabled ALL key events before I even append html

Comment: my bad. I placed the preventDefault() method before the if() statement which disabled every key event. Your code worked perfectly. Thanks Alot!